# Determine whether onPause() was fired by user navigation or by my activity launching another one

Tags: java, android, onpause

How can I determine whether `onPause()` was fired because my activity launched a new one (e.g. a photo picker intent) or because the user navigated away from my activity (e.g. by pressing home)?

Comment: if onPause followed By OnCreate and onStart its new one...

Comment: @Anshuman by then it will be too late to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to have a `state` variable in the `Activity` with some fixed values:

```
final static int RUNNING = 0;
final static int CALLED_SOMETHING = 1;

int state = RUNNING:
```

Then, whenever you launch an activity:

```
state = CALLED_SOMETHING;
```

And when it returns:

```
state = RUNNING;
```

And in your `onPause()`:

```
switch(state) {
     case RUNNING:
         // Do the stuff if Home etc were pressed
         break;
     case CALLED_SOMETHING:
         // Do the other stuff
         break;
     }
```

Obviously, you can extend this to further scenarios. You may also wish to catch `onBackPressed()` to make sure you handle the situation with as much understanding as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if nothing more proper comes along I'll accept it.